# Debye Hückel Theory valid for ions?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, condensed-matter, physical-chemistry, debye-length

I am wondering about the following:

Is [Debye Hückel Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye%E2%80%93H%C3%BCckel_theory) only used if you look at how an external "strong" field(like a potential by a sphere that has a charge that is 1000times higher than the charges of the ions) behaves in an ionic solution and how the different ions respond differently to the external field or can you use this theory also to look at how for example the field of one particular ion (let's say $Cl^{-}$) in the solution attracts let's say $Na^{+}$ or is this an invalid application of Debye Hückel's law?

If anything about my question is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Determining the free energy of a bulk electrolyte solution is also what Debye-Huckel theory is good for. It allows then to estimate the ion-ion correlations. You can look at this [fantastic review](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/bjp/v34n3b/a06v343b.pdf) by Yan Levin